# Sorting values of a column based on number of decimal places

Tags: excel, search, modulo

I am using Excel from Microsoft office 2019. also my excel skills are very underwhelming so I apologise if I don't understand something right away.

I'm trying to sort a few 100 values which i got from doing a CFD simulation (from a different program). the values i want are basically the ones which increase by 0.2, (E.G. 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ect). The other values have at least 7-8 decimal places but these ones i want have only a single decimal place.

I have tried to use the Modulus function (using 0.1 as the dividing number) however, after 0.4 all other values return something other than 0. (for example 0.6/0.1 is not zero, could be a rounding issue which i don't know how to account for.)

After Modulus failed me i decided simply sorting by number of decimal places would be just as easy however, i cant find a method to sort the values by number of decimal places.

Any help to either of these methods would be great,

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a helper column with `LEN` and `FIND` to get the number of decimal places.

Comment: Hello Sorry to be a pain, would you be able to give me a short example. thank you.

Comment: `=LEN(A1)-FIND(".",A1)`

Answer (score 0):

I had help from the Excel Reddit guys also and this solution worked. Thank you for trying to help.

Solution:

=IFERROR(IF(LEN($A1)-FIND(".",$A1,1)>1,"","Single Decimal"),"")